# unable to access user photos after login through graph API after switch app from dev mode to live mode

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I have used Facebook graph API in my react js application for accessing user images after login by the user.

```
     window.FB.login((response) => {
            if (response.authResponse) {
                const userId = response.authResponse.userID;
                window.FB.api('/me?fields=albums{photos.limit(99999){images,name,picture}}&limit=99999', (fbUser) => {
                    if(!fbUser.albums){
                      console.log( "error")// which gives only id (not giving album)
                        return;
                     }else{
                            console.log(fbUser.albums) // which contain all uploaded images 
                       }
                });
            } else {
                   console.log( "User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.")
            }
        }, error => {
            console.log(error)
        });
```

I have tested with my test account credentials and after login, it will gives me all uploaded image.

Then I have done Business verification as well as App verification for accessing user_photos According to facebook doc.

but the problem comes when I switched the verified app from "development mode" to "live mode"
and try to test with a real account then it will give me one object which contains the only id instead of the album as shown in the below pic

The code is only working for the test user account which I was created  through https://developers.facebook.com/apps/ site  and gives me all uploaded images

if I switch again from "live mode"  to "development mode" then I can access user_photos.

Please help me with this issue that is not accessing the album in live mode

[image]

Comment: Did the user get asked for the permission, when they logged in?

Comment: @CBose  no, the user did not get asked for permission.

Comment: That may be the case. Please guide me on how can I implement this  so that when the user login fb, then asked for permission,

Comment: Same as always - you ask them for it, via the login dialog.